# Как поменять версию php на сайте?

Tags: nginx, centos, vesta

Сделал все как написано [здесь](http://drach.pro/blog/linux/item/168-vestacp-podnimaem-php-do-versii-7-2-na-centos).

В консоли пишу `php -v` - получаю версию php7.2, но на сайте используется все тот же php5.4.
Подскажите какие файлы нужно еще редактировать? На сервере стоит centos7 + vestacp.

Comment: По таким вопросам, нужно обращаться к хостерам, они вам быстро помогут, но скорее всего вы просто не перезагрузили веб сервер.

Answer (score 0):

обновляли только php или и про php-frm не забыли?
Если забыли, то доставляйте, и в настройках nginx (/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default или в самом /etc/nginx/nginx.conf) смотрите в сторону этого:

fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;

Comment: у меня похоже нет php-frm. Ввел команду "systemctl status php-fpm.service" - получил "Unit php-fpm.service could not be found."

Comment: так он и не отзовется. тут читайте https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915147/php-fpm-check-if-running/20071968